# "You laid down your life that I would be set free." Why is "would" used here?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> You laid down your life that I would be set free.

In this sentence, I was wondering what's the role and meaning of 'would'.
And in my short knowledge, Isn't it right that 'so' should be at the front of 'that'? 
It'd be grateful if you could help me to satisfy my curiousity. Thank you for your time.

source: Phil Wickham's song 'This is amazing grace' lyrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'That' is a literary /  old-fashioned to archaic alternative for 'so that' (it has numerous other usages).

[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/that) gives:

> **that** conj (subordinating)
>
> 12. [Also: *so that* or *in order that*] used to introduce a clause of purpose: *they fought that others might have peace*.

.................

'Would' is the modal often used ('could' often works too) after 'so that' when introducing a (usually engineered: the 'in order to' sense) consequence, in a past time-frame:

'I lost weight so that I would fit into my old suit for the wedding'

(compare 'I am losing weight so that I will fit into my old suit for the wedding').

(And note that using 'that' here would sound ludicrous.)

.................

In 'The winter nights got colder and colder, so that the birds in the bushes would huddle together for warmth', the 'so that' is not the 'in order that' sense but purely the 'with the result that' sense, and 'would' is now the habitual past-time-frame usage. Here, 'that' is not a possibility at all.